# Delete flow by cookie match in Pox?

Tags: sdn, openflow

Is it possible to delete flow matching a certain cookie number using Pox controller for OpenFlow?
I tried something like:

```
def delete_flow(dpid,cookie):
   msg = of.ofp_flow_mod()
   msg.match=of.ofp_match()

   msg.match.cookie=cookie
   msg.match.cookie_mask=0xffffffff

   msg.command=of.OFPFC_DELETE
   msg.flags = of.OFPFF_SEND_FLOW_REM    

   sw = switches[dpid]
   if sw.connection is None: return
   sw.connection.send(msg)
   log.info("Flow %i deleted from sw %i" %(cookie,dpid))
```

but it looks like all flows are removed from all switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

According to the [OpenFlow 1.0 specification](https://www.opennetworking.org/images/stories/downloads/sdn-resources/onf-specifications/openflow/openflow-spec-v1.0.0.pdf) (since you are using POX, I can assume that is the version you are using.) the cookie field is only used to identify a flow retrieved via flow stats or expired.

> The cookie field is an opaque data value that is set by the controller. It is not used in any matching functions, and thus does not need to reside in hardware.

If you want to delete or modify using the cookie you need to use OpenFlow 1.1 or later.From the [OF 1.1 specification](http://archive.openflow.org/documents/openflow-spec-v1.1.0.pdf):

> Modify and delete commands can also be filtered by cookie value, if the cookie_mask field contains
>   a value other than 0. This constraint is that the bits specified by the cookie_mask in both the
>   cookie field of the flow mod and a flow’s cookie value must be equal. In other words, (flow.cookie &
>   flow mod.cookie mask) == (flow mod.cookie & flow mod.cookie mask).